# Multiple IBOutlets (from different classes) to One Object

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, iboutlet

Just a quick semantic question, but is it considered OK to have multiple `IBOutlets`, located in different classes, going to one (for example) NSButton in Interface Builder. The reason I ask is I need to enable and disable an NSButton based on events that happen in different classes. Would multiple IBOutlets be OK, or should I be creating a controller class for the Button that would receive a message telling it to change the sate of the button, resulting in only one IBOutlet?

Thanks in advance.

---

@Wain

The relevant code for the MergeFilesController.h file:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet NSButton *mergeFilesButton;

-(void)setMergeFilesButtonState:(BOOL)yn;
```

Relevant code for MergeFilesController.m file:

```
- (IBAction)mergeFiles:(id)sender {

   //Code goes here
}

- (void)setMergeFilesButtonState:(BOOL)yn {

    [mergeFilesButton setHidden:yn];
}
```

I have another class (called DragDropController) that controls some drag-and-drop functionality for an NSView. From the DragDropController.m file, I want to be able to change the state of the mergeFilesButton based on some stuff that happens from within the DragDropController class.

It is from the `DragDropController` class that I was trying to call `setMergeFilesButtonState`.

Comment: Use controller class.

Comment: Now that's method and argument names that communicate the intention... please get into the habbit of using meaningful names, i.e. -(void)setMergeFilesButtonHidden:(BOOL)hidden;

Comment: @Eiko this was just something quick I whipped up for personal testing purposes. I completely agree with your point, I wasn't expecting to have to share the code in this state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a controller class. View classes should be used for displaying and hosting controls. Controls should pass interaction details to the controller. The controller should control all of the views.

---

`DragDropController` should be generic and not know about the other controller specifically. Instead it should post a notification as it's state changes and other controllers can observe the notifications to determine when updates should be made to the UI.

Comment: By "controls" I assume you mean any UI Element?

Comment: Interactive UI elements. Buttons and such. Things with gestures attached are similar but the gesture should already be fully controlled by the controller.

Comment: OK, thanks. How would you recommend writing such a method. If I just write a simple setter and try to call it with `[ClassName setButtonState:NO]`, I get an error saying "No known class method for 'setButtonState'.

Comment: Where did you write it? How does it relate to the controller / IBOutlet / button action ?

Comment: Apologies, I quite new to Cocoa/Objective-C. I wrote the method in (what I think is) the controller class for the button. This class has the IBOutlet as a property. This class also contains an IBAction method, also attached to the button. I tried to call the `setButtonState` method from another class, I imported the header file of the controller class. Cheers.

Comment: What other class? Only the controller should know about changing the button. Add a method to the controller .h file. Call the method on the instance of the controller.